# Autocomplete with load on scroll in JQuery/Classic ASP

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, autoload, onscroll

There is a autocomplete textbox in classic ASP. Minimum length is set to 4 but it is very slow the autocomplete list returns more than 500 records.

log in console returns expected result and if less than 500 rows, correct list is returned in autocomplete textbox.

If I want to load more data while scrolling instead of loading the page, what would be the best method?

```
$(document).ready( function(){  
    var availableCode = new Array();
    var strCode = "";

    <%
    Dim idxJs
    for idxJs = 0 to UBound(CodeList)-1 
    %>
        availableCode[<%=idxJs %>] = unescape('<%= Escape(CodeList(idxJs)) %>');

    <% next %>

    function customFilter(array, terms) {
        arrayOfTerms = terms.split(" ");
        var term = $.map(arrayOfTerms, function (tm) {
             return $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(tm);
        }).join('|');
       var matcher = new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)("+term+")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)" , "i");
        return $.grep(array, function (value) {
            console.log("result - " + matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value));
            console.log("value - " + value)
           return matcher.test(value.slice(0, 10));
        });
    };

    $( "#frmCode" ).autocomplete({
      multiple: true,
      mustMatch: false,
      minLength: 4,
      delay: 100,
      search: function (event,ui) {
       window.pageIndex = 0;
      },
      source: function (request, response) {
        response(customFilter(
        availableCode, request.term));
      }
    });
} );
```

Some updates:
In the beginning of the classic ASP code, I added the below for cache control, it made some improving but it is still not working.

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%

Response.buffer=true
Response.Expires = -1
Response.ExpiresAbsolute = Now() -1 
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
Response.AddHeader "cache-control", "private" 
Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"

%>
```

Comment: The obvious answer here is return less than 200 rows. You shouldn't really need any more than that anyway as you'd just be flooding the user with information.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I understand that it should not be a big number of records. However, our users provided requirements that even if it is more than 1500 records, everything has to be listed as long as the user input matches with database.

Comment: Ouch. That's going to be a lot of data transferred then appended to the DOM. I'd suggest avoiding jQuery and using plain JS methods instead if you want to speed things up, although my guess would be that it'll be in vain with that many records per request

Comment: Not sure about your requirements and the time frame for your project. You can use Ehcache to put your database entries in a file and read from that file. Should be much faster. http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan We changed RegExp condition to var matcher = new RegExp("^"+"(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)("+term+")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)" , "i") - added "^" in the beginning but it could still return almost 5k records with some specific keywords.. Is there any other way we can try?

Comment: @user8271644 Thank you for your suggestion but we are not allowed to use a third vendor's software on this..

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Do you think I can use lazy load with this issue?

Comment: You could, but you'd need to find a different plugin that supports it, or write your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the matcher, I made a change to the below.

```
var matcher = new RegExp("" + term,  "i");
```

I also added "slice" to show only the top 100. This made a significant performance improvement on this issue.

```
$( "#frmCode" ).autocomplete({
    multiple: true,
    multipleSeparator: " ",
    mustMatch: false,
    minLength: 2,
    search: function (event,ui) {
    window.pageIndex = 0;
},
source: function (request, response) {
    response(customFilter(
    availableCode, request.term).slice(0, 100));
 }
```

Thank you to everyone for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

One of the bottlenecks is outputting data to the array CodeList then looping through the data and writing each separate line to populate your javascript array. If the data in the array CodeList does not change frequently, I use a scheduled task to run a few times a day that runs a vbscript to generate the html/asp page with the javascript array sans the asp loop.  You would replace your for/next asp loop with the actual javascript array data. The page will load much faster.